# Implementing filterAcceptsRows for filtering on a foreign key

Tags: python, pyside2, qsortfilterproxymodel

I've found several answers to my question below but I can't seem to work out how to implement them in my case.

What I'm trying to do is connect a ComboBox to a QTableView, where the int id from the selected row of the ComboBox will be used to filter a Foreign Key of the model attached to a QTableView.

Let's say we have a `personnel` table with a `person_company_fk` foreign key column. This table is displayed in a QTableView through a model. The model is parsed though a filter, subclassed from QSortFilterProxyModel.

I've connected

```
self.currentIndexChanged.connect(self.personnelFilteredModel.FilterData(company_id))
```

so that any change in selection in the ComboBox sends the ID to the filtered model.

My problem is that the model does not refresh, and even though everything is connected, the QTableView does not change (no errors either). I believe my problem lies with how I'm calling `dataChanged.emit()`. By the way, if I set the `self.fkFilter` to a value in the `__init__`, the model displays the filtered rows.

Can you help out?

```
class CustomFilterModel(QtCore.QSortFilterProxyModel):
    def __init__(self):
        super(CustomFilterModel,self).__init__()
        self.fkColumnIndex=None
        self.nameColumnIndex=None
        self.fkFilter=None
        self.setDynamicSortFilter(True)

    def FilterData(self,fk):
        self.fkFilter=fk
        x=self.rowCount()
        y=self.columnCount()
        self.dataChanged.emit(self.index(0,0),self.index(x,y))

    def filterAcceptsRow(self, source_row:int, source_parent:QtCore.QModelIndex) -> bool:
        if (self.fkFilter !=None) and (self.fkColumnIndex !=None):
            x=self.createIndex(source_row,self.fkColumnIndex)
            j=int(self.sourceModel().data(x))
            if j==self.fkFilter:
                return True
            else:
                return False
        else:
            return True
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to call the [`invalidateFilter`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsortfilterproxymodel.html#invalidateFilter) method for the filter to apply.

```py
def FilterData(self,fk):
    self.fkFilter = fk
    self.invalidateFilter()
```

On the other hand the filterAcceptsRow method can be improved:

```py
def filterAcceptsRow(self, source_row:int, source_parent:QtCore.QModelIndex) -> bool:
    if self.fkFilter and self.fkColumnIndex:
        ix = self.sourceModel().index(source_row, self.fkColumnIndex)
        text = ix.data()
        return text == self.fkFilter
    return True
```

Comment: Thank you! And for simplifying the other code aswell, I know my code is a mess as I'm still really new to programming. It's the first mention of `self.invalidateFilter()` I've seen so far and it works perfectly.